# Rational sextic plane curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In Coolidge's venerable *Treatise on algebraic plane curves*, Theorem 28 p. 392 states:

- Let $S=\{P_1,\ldots ,P_{10}\} \subset \mathbb{P}^2$  such that for any $i$,   there is a sextic curve (**edit**: integral) singular along $S\smallsetminus P_i$; then there is a sextic curve singular along $S$.

I am probably missing something, but it seems to me that the text before and after this statement has nothing to do with the Theorem. Does someone know a proof?

Comment: Isn't it true that the assumption on $S$ holds for any $S$ by dimension count?

Comment: No, for 9 general points $P_1,\ldots ,P_9$ there does not exist a sextic singular along the $P_i$ — there is a unique (smooth) cubic $E$ through the $P_i$, and on $E$ the divisor $2\sum P_i$ must be equivalent to $6 \ell_{|E}$, where $\ell$ is a line. The point is that whenever a sextic is singular at 9 points, there is actually a pencil of such sextics — the original one and the double cubic.

Comment: But the double cubic IS a sextic singular at all these points. So, perhaps in your assumption you want a reduced (and maybe irreducible) sextic, right?

Comment: You are right, let us say irreducible. I edit the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me try to reconstruct Coolidge's argument at pages 390-392.

**Note:** there is a misprint at line 4 of p. 392, where "with double points" should be "with triple points".

> **Proposition 1 [Coolodge, p. 390-391].** Assume that $P_1, \ldots, P_8$ are points on the plane, not three on a line and not six on a conic. Let $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ be a basis for the pencil of cubics through the $P_i$ and let $f$ be a non-degenerate sextic with the $P_i$ as double points. Then a point $P_9$ is a further double point of a non-degenerate sextic with double points at $P_1, \ldots,  P_8$ if and only if it is a smooth point of the curve $$\frac{\partial(\phi_1, \, \phi_2, \, f)}{\partial(x_1, \, x_2, \, x_3)}=0.$$
> This curve has triple points at each of the points $P_1, \ldots, P_8$ and passes simply through the $12$ singular points of the nodal curves of the pencil of cubics spanned by $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$.

> **Proposition 2 [Coolidge, Theorem 27, p. 391].** Assume that nine points of the plane are the base locus of a pencil of nodal sextics. Then there are precisely $12$ sextics in the pencil having a further double point.

Using these results, we can now prove the

> **Theorem.** Assume that $P_1, \ldots, P_{10}$ is a set of ten points such that for any nine of them there is a non-degenerate sextic (and hence a pencil of non-degenerate sextics) having nodes there . Then there is a non-degenerate sextic having nodes at all of the ten points.

**Proof.** Consider the nodal sextics through $P_1, \ldots P_8$. Since by assumption there is a nodal sextic through $P_1, \ldots, P_9$, we deduce that $P_9$ is a smooth point of the curve $C$ of degree $9$ and with triple points at $P_1, \ldots, P_8$ described in Proposition $1$. Analogously, consider the nodal sextics through $P_1, \ldots, P_7, \, P_9$. Then $P_8$ is a smooth point of the curve $D$ of degree $9$ and with triple points at $P_1, \ldots, P_7, \, P_9$.

The $12$ nodal points $Q_1, \ldots, Q_{12}$ of the $12$ singular curves of the pencil of nodal sextics through $P_1, \ldots, P_9$ (see Proposition 2) must belong to both $C$ and $D$. Moreover, since $$9\cdot 9 - 7 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 - 3 \cdot 1 - 1 \cdot 3 = 12,$$ the only intersection points of $C$ and $D$ are $P_1, \ldots, P_9$ and $Q_1, \ldots, Q_{12}$.

Finally, by assumption we also have pencils of nodal sextics through $P_1, \ldots, P_8, \, P_{10}$ and through $P_1, \ldots, P_7, \, P_9, \, P_{10}$. Then $P_{10}$ belongs to the intersection of $C$ and $D$, too. By the remark above, this means that $P_{10}=Q_i$ for some $i$.

Summing up, there is a curve in the pencil of nodal sextics through $P_1, \ldots, P_9$ which has a further node at $P_{10}$. This concludes the proof.

Comment: Thanks very much! I had seen Proposition 1 and 2 in Coolidge but failed to see the relation with the result. I must say I was hoping for something more conceptual, but perhaps this doesn't exist.

Comment: You are welcome. It looks like some variation on the Cayley-Bacharach argument, but I do not know whether  there exists some modern version of this providing the conceptual framework you are looking for.